# ActiveMQ: Creating a Broker in cmd and running two broker in parallel

Tags: embedded, jms, activemq-classic, messagebroker, broker

How to create a new broker like localost2:5555 url in cmd, and having problem with running producer in one server and consumer in another. Configured for failover service too. but when consumer server gets restarted producer not able to send messages to consumer.

Comment: You need to better define what it is you are doing and what you want to accomplish

Comment: Simple.. i have one producer and consumer,, following request reply method of transport. Now i started my consumer then started my producer. Now if i stop my consumer , suddenly producer throwing ssl connection refused exception. But when i start the consumer , producer couldnt able to bind it back....

Comment: dont know why producer getting interrupted when consumer gets restarted... please help..